# mysql - is today between two column values

Tags: mysql, sql, date, between

```
| id         | first (datetime)    | last (datetime)
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2013-04-15 00:00:00 | 2013-04-21 23:59:00
| 2          | 2013-04-08 00:00:00 | 2013-04-14 23:59:00
| 3          | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 2013-04-07 23:59:00
| 4          | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 2013-04-07 23:59:00
```

I want to show records if records datetime range covers today. (3 and 4 for this sample)

I tried do this with two `NOW()`, it gives syntax error in second `NOW()`.

How can i do this?

Comment: show your query please

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE NOW() BETWEEN...

Comment: This depends.  Do you need the exact current time to fall between these two times, or do you just want to know if any part of the current data falls in between those times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    *
from
    your_table
where
    first <= NOW() 
and last >= NOW()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from your_table
where current_date() between first_datetime and last_datetime
```